# How to assign weights to a set of features Linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am making a machine learning program just with a simple linear regression. In the dataset, I have two types of features: 
   Low dimension features: e.g. word count, length, etc. 
   High dimension features: TFIDF features

I just to want to manually assign weights on different set of features.

I have been trying with pipleline featureunion (transformer_weights), but I find it is difficult to do so if I want to have a TFIDF feature built from a vocabulary created by both train and test data.

Could you please advice if there are any solution other than using pipeline?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want to manually assign the weights? Why don't you represent the weight assignment problem as a cost minimization problem and minimize the cost function to get the optimal weights with the least amount of error?  Something like gradient descent, or least-squares is suitable.

Comment: Hi rayryeng, initially I tried to put all features together (low dimension and high dimension) and fit them with linear regression model, however, I found that if I manually assign weights to blocks of features, the result was better.